# oracle sql - a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I know there are loads of postings regarding fixing this error but, I'm just not understanding it!

`val_strg1` value is `01.04.2016`. I want to use this and not show lines where this date is older than current date, (i.e. `and trunc(sysdate) < dv.val_strg1`).

But, even though I have used a to_date format, I still get the `a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` error?

I have tried several to_date formats;

`to_date(val_strg1,'DDMMYYYY')`, `to_date(val_strg1,'DD-MM-YYYY')`

The following gives me a `'not a valid month'` error?

```
to_date(val_strg1,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

My script...

```
select val_strg, val_strg1, to_date(val_strg1,'DDMMYYYY')
from sd_domainval_org 
where name = 'HYPERCARE_CUNR'
order by sort_no
```

How can I use the `val_strg1` as a date?

Comment: Why are you using hyphens in your format string if the values contain periods?

Comment: I get the same error when using to_date(val_strg1,'DD.MM.YYYY')

Comment: What are all values you have for `val_strg1`?

Comment: Data type for val_strg1?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a text column (e.g. VARCHAR2) for the date. And you are saying that

```
to_date(val_strg1, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

results in an error. So you have a value in that column that does not match the pattern. Here is a query to find such invalid entries:

```
select * 
from domainval
where name = 'HYPERCARE_CUNR'
and not regexp_like(val_strg1, '^[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{4}$');
```

You can then correct the wrong entries, but a better solution would of course be not to store dates in string columns at all. Use date columns instead, so as to not have such issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the column type. It is indeed a date inserted in a text column but, I cannot access the column (this is a very historic set up in our system and cannot be changed). Is there another way of using the text as a date?

Comment: If you cannot change the table design then maybe you can at least add a check constraint that ensures the date format.

Answer (score 0):

if your string date val_strg1 is in the form 'DD.MM.YYYY' (i.e. '01.04.2016'), then you have to use to_date(val_strg1,'DD.MM.YYYY');
for example: Select to_date('01.04.2016','DD.MM.YYYY') from dual;
If you have errors again, probably you have a string in the recordset that is not in a valid form for the to_date function (check the values in the val_strg1 column).
Bye,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer...

```
and trunc(sysdate) < to_date(regexp_substr(val_strg1, '^[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]]{4}$'),'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

...seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

you have to tune formating string to exactly match your date structure 
in this case

```
select val_strg, val_strg1, to_date(val_strg1,'DD.MM.YYYY')
from sd_domainval_org 
where name = 'HYPERCARE_CUNR'
order by sort_no;
```